# Unpacking Inno Setup installers with InnoExtractor?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, pe, unpacking, executable

I want to know how to use the application [InnoExtractor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/InnoExtractor.shtml) to unpack/extract the files of Inno Setup installers. Some good tutorial/video to learn?

I get this application from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Compression-tools/InnoExtractor.shtml).

Comment: I don't think you need a tutorial for just using InnoExtractor. If you want to look into how it works, you should either search if the source code is available, or reverse engineer it.

Comment: You could use [Innounp](http://innounp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You can download InnoSetup's source code on GitHub. This will help you understand how the files are packed: https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc

Comment: @Ange: InnoExtractor is a front-end GUI for Innounp.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. Look... I have an installer based on Inno Setup and I need to learn how to use InnoExtractor to unpack/extract files of the installer and later repack them again with my own files. Is this possible?